# Incrementing the row in a loop using a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search down a column of an excel sheet for identical text which is an argument of the function.

```
Function getRow(callerID As String) As Integer
Dim CalcRow As Integer
Dim CurrRow As Integer
Dim CurrCol As Integer
Dim SearchSheet As Worksheet

'Define variables
Set SearchSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations")
Set CellSearch = SearchSheet.Cells(CurrRow,CurrCol)
CalcRow = 2
CurrRow = 2
CurrCol = 16

Do Until CellSearch.Value = ""

    If callerID = CellSearch.Value Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        CurrRow = CurrRow + 1
        CalcRow = CalcRow + 1
    End If
Loop

'set return value
getRow = CalcRow

End Function
```

It keeps saying this is an error: `Set CellSearch = SearchSheet.Cells(CurrRow,CurrCol)` when I try to refer to it as a range.

I've tried referring to the range in other ways --I just want to increment the row by 1 until each cell in that column with a value is searched.

I'm very new to VBA so I've had some trouble with referring to cells without using ActiveCell. I don't want to use ActiveCell for this.

Comment: Note: you can use `Application.Match` or `Range.Find` to do this without a loop.

Comment: `Set CellSearch = SearchSheet.Cells(CurrRow,CurrCol)` doesn't work because at that point `CurrRow` and `CurrCol` are both equal to `0`, and there is no row or column 0.

Comment: Thank you for that additional information on Application.Match/Range.Find!!!! I will see if I can fix what I have then investigate those functions further.

Comment: Another issue: `Set CellSearch = SearchSheet.Cells(CurrRow,CurrCol)` - `CellSearch` will always refer to the same cell (assuming the row and column are valid inputs). You need to "reset" it inside your loop... which is a clunky approach. Best to scrap this attempt and use `Match` or `Find`.

Comment: Also: [Use `Long`, not `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: Thanks again! I just looked up a youtube video that also explained the Index function which might be helpful. This is a lot easer than what I was trying to do! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIGH-Q8cnrI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get the Worksheet Row of the First Occurrence of a String in a Column

- To allow to find other data types (Numbers, Dates, Booleans...) you only have to change

  ```
  callerID As Variant
  ```
- Note that `Application.Match` is case-insensitive i.e. `MYSTRING = mystring`. Also, it is handled differently than `WorksheetFunction.Match` i.e. its result can be tested with `IsError` or `IsNumeric` while the `WorksheetFunction` version will raise an error if no match is found.
- [`Range.Resize Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)
- Keep in mind that the [`Range.Find method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) is unreliable if the worksheet is filtered.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function getRow(callerID As String) As Long
    ' Define the First Cell
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("P2")
        ' Calculate the Row Offset which is utilized with resize
        ' and when writing the result.
        Dim RowOffset As Long: RowOffset = .Row - 1
        ' Declare a range variable.
        Dim rg As Range
        ' Attempt to define the Last Non-Empty Cell.
        Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - RowOffset) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        ' Validate the Last Non-Empty Cell.
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then
            ' Define the Column Range, the range from the First Cell
            ' to the Last Non-Empty Cell in the worksheet column.
            Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - RowOffset)
            ' Attempt to find the Index (position) of the Caller ID
            ' in the Column Range.
            Dim cIndex As Variant: cIndex = Application.Match(callerID, rg, 0)
            ' Validate the Index i.e. check if the Caller ID was found.
            If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                ' Write the result. Note that the Index is the position
                ' in the Column Range, so to return the position (row)
                ' in the worksheet, the Row Offset has to be added.
                getRow = cIndex + RowOffset
            'Else ' Caller ID was not found (cIndex is an error value).
            End If
        'Else ' The range from the First Cell to the bottom-most cell
            ' of the worksheet column is empty.
        End If
    End With
End Function
```